# woocommerce check how many products of the category wine are inside the cart

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, custom-taxonomy

I'm trying to make a condition, where a function displays in cart page only, if any product from category wine is present in the cart and how much.

1. Problem: Currently it does shows me a info of only 1 wine, when i have more different wines in the cart, instead to count all wines.
2. Problem: i want to drop a message when there are

   - 10, 13, 16 or 19 Bottles in the cart = message 1
   - 11, 14, 17 or 20 Bottles in the cart = message 2

At the moment it works with 1 (e.g. 10) separated number only.

Here is the code:

```
add_action( 'xoo_wsc_after_footer_btns', 'bbloomer_check_category_in_cart' );
function bbloomer_check_category_in_cart() {
// Set $cat_in_cart to false
$cat_in_cart = false;
$cat_count = 0; 
$product_count = 0;
// Loop through all products in the Cart  foreach(WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item)
foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {

 $product = $cart_item['data'];
   
  // If Cart has category "download", set $cat_in_cart to true
  if ( has_term( 'wein', 'product_cat', $cart_item['product_id'] ) ) {
     $cat_in_cart = true;
      $product_count += $cart_item['quantity'];

     break;
  }
}
// Do something if category "download" is in the Cart
if ( $cat_in_cart && $product_count == 10 ) {

     
  // For example, print a notice
  wc_print_notice( 'Keine halben Sachen, nur noch 2 Flaschen und der Karton ist voll. Wir belohnen dich mit "due baci"', 'notice' );
}
if ( $cat_in_cart && $product_count == 11 ) {

     
  // For example, print a notice
  wc_print_notice( 'Keine halben Sachen, nur noch 1 Flasche und der Karton ist voll. Wir belohnen dich mit "due baci"', 'notice' );
 }
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try removing the break;  You don't want to break, you want it to loop through all the cart items and check if it has the category of wein.

Comment: That´s it!! It works.. :) ty very much for your fast answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the break; You don't want to break, you want it to loop through all the cart items and check if it has the category of wein

Posted as comment originally but now the answer